# Test fails and I can't figure out why 

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a `LandingScreen` component that contains a `onPositivePermission` function. In this function, I call a static login method from my `FacebookConnector`. I want to test that the login method is indeed called in `onPositivePermission`. I have tried different tests, but none of them work. My components are as follows:

LandingScreen

```
class LandingScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.loginMethods = { 
             fbLogin: 0, 
             emailLogin: 1, 
         } 
    }

onPositivePermission = loginMethod => {
    if (loginMethod === this.loginMethods.fbLogin) 
        { FacebookConnector.login(); 
    } 
};
```

FacebookConnector

```
export default class FacebookConnector {
    static login = async() => { 
        try { const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([                                    'public_profile', 'email', ]); 
        if (result.isCancelled) { 
            //do nothing, the user cancelled 
        } else { 
            //handle Facebook login } 
    } catch (error) { 
        //handle error  
        } 
    };
```

And this is my test:

```
  it('Calls the Facebook login method', () => {
    const fbLogin = 0;
    const landingScreen = renderer.create(<LandingScreen />).getInstance();
    let loginMock = jest.fn();
    jest.mock('../../connectors/Facebook/FacebookConnector', () => ({
      default: class {
        static login() {
          mock.loginMock;
        }
      },
    }));

    landingScreen.onPositivePermission(fbLogin);
    expect(loginMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I also tried to mock FacebookConnector as follows:

```
jest.mock('../../connectors/Facebook/FacebookConnector', () => ({
      login: mock.loginMock,
    }));
```

However, in both cases I get:

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
 Expected number of calls: >= 1
 Received number of calls:    0
```

I have added logs in my `onPositivePermission()` function and saw that it is indeed called by the test, but nevertheless the expect statement fails.

I have also tried removing the if statement in `onPositivePermission();`  expect still fails.

Note that I tested the functionality manually and `FacebookConnector.login()` *is* called, but I also want to unit test it.

Does anyone have a clue why the unit test is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login` is a static method in the `FacebookConnector` class, so you can mock it in the following way.

```
it('Calls the Facebook login method', () => {
  const fbLogin = 0;
  const landingScreen = renderer.create(<LandingScreen />).getInstance();

  const loginMock = jest.fn();
  loginMock.mockReturnValue('some value');
  FacebookConnector.login = loginMock;

  landingScreen.onPositivePermission(fbLogin); 
  expect(loginMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

P.S. You don't need to add a return value, it should work without that.

Let's make it clearer: 
`expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()` won't work because jest.fn() hasn't been actually called. You only create a jest.fn instance and expect it to be called.

but if you assign this to a variable and then if you call that function

```
const someFunction = jest.fn(); //creating a jest.fn instance
someFunction(); //we are calling the function here.
expect(someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled() // it will pass
```

it will work without a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! :) One question though: what is the point of 
`loginMock.mockReturnValue('some value');
FacebookConnector.login = loginMock;`?
The `login()` method from `FacebookConnector` doesn't return any value in the production code, so I'm a bit confused as to why we need the two lines above.